# Ember JS minified with Ember-Skel

Tags: ember.js, minify

I tried minifying an Ember JS application. I am using the Ember-Skel Tools to compile the JS app and to minify them. When I set the RAKEP_MODE to production, it usually minifies the JS and CSS. When I compile it in non Production mode, everything works fine, but then when I minify this, one particular view is not found any more. Any pointers as to why this happens.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the most likely culprit is a syntax error in the object immediately preceding the missing one. Take a look at the un-minified version and see what is right before the view in question. Does it end with a `;`? Are all `(`, `[`, and `{` matched with `)`, `]`, and `}`?